# ricfaces xhtml edit problem for jetty

Tags: xhtml, richfaces, jetty, restart

I am using Richfaces with facelets (xhtml). I use maven jetty plugin for development.

When jetty is running, I modify a xhtml file but the change does not work until I restart jetty.

Here is my maven jetty plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jettyEnvXml>${basedir}/src/test/resources/${jetty-env-file}</jettyEnvXml>
                    <webDefaultXml>${basedir}/src/test/resources/webdefault.xml</webDefaultXml>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I edit css, jsp or html files I can see the changes without restarting.

But for xhtml files in every change I need to restart jetty again and again.

Is there any solution for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It is all about the facelet configuration parameters in web.xml.
After I changed them, i can update xhtml files while jetty is up and running.
Here is the link that i found appropriate facelet parameterconfiguration:

http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/facelets/03-FaceletsConcepts/facelets-configuration.jsf

Answer (score 0):

In case the above link ever disappears, in web.xml of your faces application do add this:

---

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>
```